# How do I create a automatic "next delivery time " text line in wordpress php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

So I have been coding a little custom line on my wordpress site using php, that should show the next delivery time automatically.

[image: line that I have right now]
Right now it shows 2 automatically updating dates for 2 of the week days.
What I would want is them to cycle, so if it's less then 24 hours till lets say the fridays delivery you can't see that text. It would only show the other option.
This is the code that I currently have.
`

```
<p class="mb-4 fw-bold"><?php
            _e('Järgmised tarneajad', 'esahver'); 
            echo ": " ;

            $now = strtotime("now");
            $next_delivery = strtotime('next tuesday');

            $limit_hours = 17;
            $next_delivery_minus_hrs = strtotime('-' . $limit_hours . ' hours', $next_delivery);
            $final_next_delivery = NULL;
            if( $next_delivery_minus_hrs < $now ){ // past limit hours
              $next2_delivery = strtotime('next tuesday', $next_delivery);
              $final_next_delivery = wp_date( 'l, d.m.Y' , $next2_delivery);
            } else {
              $final_next_delivery = wp_date( 'l, d.m.Y' , $next_delivery );
            }
              
            $now1 = strtotime("now");
            $next_delivery1 = strtotime('next friday');
            
            $limit_hours1 = 17;
            $next_delivery_minus_hrs1 = strtotime('-' . $limit_hours1 . ' hours', $next_delivery1);
            $final_next_delivery1 = NULL;
            if( $next_delivery_minus_hrs1 < $now ){ // past limit hours
              $next2_delivery1 = strtotime('next friday', $next_delivery1);
              $final_next_delivery1 = wp_date( 'l, d.m.Y' , $next2_delivery1);
            } else {
              $final_next_delivery1 = wp_date( 'l, d.m.Y' , $next_delivery1 );
            }
              
            
              
             
            echo $final_next_delivery;
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='custom_delivery_date' value='".$final_next_delivery."'/>";
            echo " & ";
            echo $final_next_delivery1;
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='custom_delivery_date' value='".$final_next_delivery1."'/>";
          ?>
          </p>
```

`
How would I approach this problem?
Thanks

I have tried writing some bad if sentences that didn't work out at all.

Comment: So you want to hide a date if it's less than 24 hours until that date, correct?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the code even more simply

Comment: That's not helpful or even answering the question. Use answers only to provide useful informations to help